# How do I reverse the coordinates with mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I have these coordinates in the wrong order I need to reverse them for all collections:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("638f9866d9014fabfc47275e"),
  address: '801 Pine St, Anchorage, AK',
  name: 'Russian Jack Skatepark',
  location: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [ 61.214855, -149.793563 ] }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$reverseArray](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/operator/aggregation/reverseArray/) as follow:

```
db.collection.updateMany({},
[
{
$set: {
  "location.coordinates": {
    $reverseArray: "$location.coordinates"
   }
  }
 }
])
```

[Playgrouund](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NKVVYcMG9lJ)

Comment: That deleted my entire collection.

Comment: @chovy : How is that possible , what command you have used? Also the provided above can update only single document , you need to add {multi:true} to affect all documents...

Comment: i got an error. and it said to use `updateMany()`

Comment: can you add example for all docs?

Comment: Updated the answer to updateMany()

Comment: That deleted the collection.

Comment: I can't beleive it ... , perhaps you did something else ...